# How to import a plugin in Eclipse luna 4.4.2

Tags: java, eclipse

how to  import the IBM worklight studio 6.3 and Mobile First Test Workbench plugin into the eclipse luna 4.4.2, I tried on eclipse luna--> help--> Market place and I search these plugins they are having the version 7. and above.

I download these s/w on internet but I don't know how to import these plugins.

anybody can help me this.

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse luna and this is the process that i use when i want to install a plug-in [Eclipse Luna install plug-in tutorial](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/install_plugin/index_v35.html)

I hope it could answer your question.